# Redirect after front end deleting post

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a delete post button on the front end for a Wordpress site. It deletes the post fine but then tries to reload the post again causing a 404. Is there a way I redirect it after deleting to a specific url? This is my code:

```
function wp_delete_post_link($link = 'Delete This', $before = '', $after = '') {
    global $post;
    $link = "<a href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'>".$link."</a>";
    echo $before . $link . $after;
}
```

Then on the template:

```
<?php wp_delete_post_link('Delete This', '<p>', '</p>'); ?>
```

Comment: Is the outcoming URL correct? Also after the first `$post->ID` you have a `,` instead of a `.`

Comment: @mparryy Yes it's `http://www.domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&post=214&_wpnonce=e9f8b62b64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `wp_redirect` function.

```
$location = 'http://domainname.com/pagename/';
$status = '301';

wp_redirect( $location, $status );

exit;
```

Just place after your successful delete code.

Answer (score 0):

How about running this function right after your echo:

```
header( 'Location: yournewURL.html' ) ;
```

Replace 'yournewURL.html' with the page you need to redirect to.